# Usability of Web Analytics Applications

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation

Are there any usability resources out there that specifically deal with the design of an analytics web application?  I've been tasked to design a web app with a strong analytics component and I've been told there are different considerations than designing for "transactional" sites, but so far no one can point me to resources for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [collection of some design patterns](http://patterntap.com/usersets/set/5076) for analytics on patterntap.

I would go into popular analytics applications and take notes like crazy.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your colleague: you'll want to look for application usability guidelines in general, as opposed to guidelines for transactional websites such as web shops.

Here's one for [web applications](http://www.nngroup.com/reports/flash/) - it's from 2002 and for flash applications, but much of the information also applies to today's rich web apps such as yours. [Here's](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/application-mistakes.html) also a more recent list of common application design mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for the responses so far.  I also found this resource which might help me out also:

http://patterns.endeca.com/content/library/en/home/patterns/analyticsApplications.html